# Nonunique factorization in number rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, roots-of-unity, unique-factorization-domains, fermat-numbers

Can you give an example of a nonunique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/23}]$?

Can you write two different decompositions into irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/23}]$?

Comment: I think $(1 - \sqrt{-23})(1 + \sqrt{-23}) = 24 = 2^3 \cdot 3$ works.  You still have to show the factors in the two factorizations are relatively prime, but they are.

Comment: @SpamIAm yes but how do you know that $(1+\sqrt{-23})$ is irreducible?

Comment: @Mathmo123 You're right, I haven't shown that it's irreducible.  But I did check that it's relatively prime to $2$ and $3$, so if it is reducible, its irreducible factors will work.

Comment: Is $\sqrt{-23}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/23}]$?

Comment: @kato87 Yes, for any odd prime $\ell$, $\sqrt{\ell^*} \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_\ell]$, where $\ell^* = (-1)^{(\ell-1)/2} \ell = \left(\frac{-1}{\ell}\right) \ell$.  See p. 51 of Neukirch.

Answer (score 3):

An explicit counterexample is given by $6533$, which has two different decompositions, namely
$$
6533=47\cdot 139=
(1 - α + α^{21})(1 - α^2 + α^{21})\cdot \ldots \cdot(1 - α^{21} + α^{21}),
$$
for a certain $\alpha\in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$. For details see the proof [here](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.co.at/2006/07/cyclotomic-integers-unique_25.html), which is taken from Edwards book.

Another proof goes as follows: Since the ring of integers $\Bbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/23}]$
in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{23})$ is a UFD if and only if it is a PID, it is enough to see that $\Bbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/23}]$ is *not* a PID. In fact,
 the ideal $Q = (2, \frac{1 + \sqrt{-23}}{2})$ is not principal in $\Bbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/23}]$. This also leads to an explicit counterexample for unique factorization.

Comment: Quite nice, thank you